# React admin custom component inside simpleform

Tags: react-admin

Hello stackoverflow so I have a custom components inside of my create simpleform looking like this.

```
   <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm {...props}>
        <TextField id="standard-basic" onChange={onChangeLabel} value={entityLabel} placeholder="Audience label" />
        <br />
        <EntityInput onSelectEntity={addEntity} entityNames={entityNames} />
        <TagInput setSelectedTags={addSelectedTag} selectedTags={selectedTags} />
        <br />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
```

My question is how do I enable the save button and pass in custom data and tell the save button which records to create?

Comment: Created a custom component that picksup google location but it doesn't seem to activate the save button on my simple form. Did you find a solution? Mine is a client form and I want to capture google location of the client among other details

Comment: Hey so I was able to figure it out by using ```const { input } = useInput(props);``` Importing the useInput hook and applying ```input.onChange(value)``` to set the data worked for me. Hopefully that helps. Refer to https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component ```The useInput hook```